# Intersection of a line and a hyperplane in general

Tags: vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, inner-products

Let's say we have the folowing hyperplane
$$\{x|a^{T}x= b\}$$ 
where $a\in \Re^n, a\neq 0, b\in \Re$ as the set of points with a constant inner product to a given vector a. I want to prove that if the line:
$$l(t)=x+t\cdot a$$ where $t\in \Re$ intersects the hyperplane at $x_1$, then $x_1=\big(\frac{b}{||a||^2}\big)a$ where Euclidean norm is implied.

I am confused. Any clue?

Comment: $x$ does not look good in the equation of the line.

Comment: I'd rather say that $a^Tx_1=b/||a||^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pluggin the line into the hyperplane gives you $b=a^T\cdot(x+ta)=a^T\cdot x+ta^T\cdot a=a^T\cdot x+t\Vert a\Vert^2$ and thus $t=\frac{b-a^T\cdot x}{\Vert a\Vert^2}$. Plugging this into the line gives $x_1=x+\frac{b-a^T\cdot x}{\Vert a\Vert^2}a=x+\frac{b}{\Vert a\Vert^2}a-\frac{a^T\cdot x}{\Vert a\Vert^2}a=\frac{b}{\Vert a\Vert^2}a$.

Edit: As Aretino pointed out my computation is incorrect. See my comment below which gives you a counter-example to the original question's assumption.

Comment: If $x$ and $a$ are not parallel, how can it be that $x=(a^Tx)a/||a||^2$?

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that too. You're right, my answer is not correct which should automatically give you a counter-example to the original assumption.

Comment: Take $x=(1,0)$, $a=(0,1)$ and $b=1$. Then $x_1=(1,1)$ which is not equal to $\frac{1}{1}(0,1)=(0,1)$.